# How to bind list of latitude and longitude on Google Map Version 2 android

Tags: android

Is it possible to add a list of latitudes and longitudes in Google Map Version 2 in android?

I have tried using marker options which will add only one at a time. How can I add a list of them all at the same time instead of one by one?

Comment: can you post some code , what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one HashMap of Latitude and Longitude first like,

```
HashMap<String, String> mapItem;
 mapItem=new HashMap<String,String>();
 mapItem.put("Latitude",YOUR LATITUDE VALUE); 
 mapItem.put("Longitude",YOUR LONGITUDE VALUE);

 googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)).position( new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(mapItem.get("Latitude")), Double.parseDouble(markerItem.get("Longitude"))));
```

Comment: i tried same way as you mentioed but i am not able see the map when i launch application.

Answer (score 0):

Since the only method available is `GoogleMap.addMarker(Marker Options options)` there is no way to add more than one at a time as far as I know. Simply iterate through your list of lat and longs, adding a marker at each coordinate.

I also keep an `ArrayList<Marker>` containing each marker I add. This makes it easy to keep track of the markers that you have and you can manage, clear, or add to them when necessary.

EDIT: Example

```
        ArrayList<LatLng> coords;
        ArrayList<Marker> markerList;
        //Build your list of latitudes and longitudes here

        ----------------------
        for(LatLng coord : coords){
            // Add a marker at each location on the map.
            Marker m= map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(coord)
                    .title(locationName)
                    .snippet(locationAddress)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.mapPin)));
            markerList.add(m);
         }
```